# Recommended partitioning for system with 40gb SSD and 500gb HDD

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I was going to put / on the SSD and swap and /home on the HDD. The system is a office PC and has 4gb RAM. Is this the best way to partition the system?

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have almost same parameters.

I placed / and swap on ssd and no separate /home. There is not enough space on SSD to waste it on having half-empty `/` partition.

I symlinked large directories to HDD.

I use very fast hybernation from SSD.

I did not place /home on HDD because in Ubuntu there are very many small configuration files stored in hidden directories of /home.

They are accessed on system startup and when you start any application. If you place them on HDD, the system will work much slower.

Comment: Why not put /home on HDD?

Comment: I explained it in my answer.

Comment: Have a wiki link or something on how to use symlinks?

Comment: It can be found in google by "symlink ubuntu". Or here too.

Comment: But having /home on the SSD will still be faster than having everything on a HDD right?

Comment: SSD is much faster. That's it. What you open frequently must be on SSD. Large files like movies, music, photos, etc can be on HDD

Comment: I do exactly like Pilot6. Posted details of linking here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198&p=11081384#post11081384